# What is the significance of the book names' appearances?

Tags: plot-explanation, 20th-century-women

What is the significance of the book names' appearances in 20th Century Women?

Whenever a character reads a book, then its book name appears on the screen.

Is it necessary in the movie to show the title of the book every-time someone reads it?